# Transpose or mirror SpatialPoints object while retaining original extent - R

Tags: r, spatial, r-sp

Is there a way to mirror or transpose a SpatialPoints object in R? I'm interested in creating a mirrored example of some points using the same extent or X/Y limits as in original example and relatively same spatial relationship. I tried reversing one of the coordinate columns but that does not achieve the mirroring result because the middle point does not move.

Some data:

```
library(sp)

df <- SpatialPoints(cbind(c(-110.3,-110.4,-110.9), c(42.3,42.5,42.7)), CRS("+init=epsg:4326"))

plot(df)
```

[image: Left image plot of original points. Right image example of expected results with transposed/mirrored coordinates of points.]

Comment: Looks like you are just reflecting across a vertical line at 110.6 degrees W. So you'd only be modifying the longitude (x) coordinate. The reflection in this case would be `(2 * -110.6) - c(-110.3,-110.4,-110.9)`

Comment: @qdread Thanks. This is just a toy example but are you suggesting I could take the midline of the longitude values and do as you suggest..I'll try that.

Answer (score 0):

As @qdread points out in the comments the solution is quite simple.

`(2 * median(x.coords)) - x.coords`